# Blender editor scaling problem

Tags: objects

I'm very new to Blender as this is the first time I am working with it. I'm following the following instructions to create a simple coffee cup: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y__uzGKmxt8. However I got the problem when I wanted to scale the cup like the guy in the video did at 5:05. I got this:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Pivot Point

You set the **3D Cursor** as [transformation pivot point](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/pivot_point/index.html) while the youtuber is using **Median point** (see the icon pointed by the mouse arrow in the orange box):

[image: pivot point menu]

With the pivot point in the middle of selection he is able to scale the geometry from its center, not from side in your case. You can clearly see the pivot location by looking for the trasformation gizmo (colored arrows pointing towars axis)

You can change the pivot point in the button menu:

[image]

Comment: Would suggest cropping images slightly less or expanding on your description as it might not be immediately clear where the pivot point menu is located.

Comment: Suggestion accepted @RayMairlot! Thanks for pointing it out.